# Java Scanner hasNext() doesn't return false

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read input continuously from the user until the user types quit. I am testing it by just typing 'quit' but console.hasNext() doesn't seem to be returning false. In fact it seems that the program is blocked on line 7(hasNext() line). Any ideas?

```
    boolean bool = true;
    while (bool) {
        System.out.println("Type 'quit':");
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        if (console.next().equals("quit")) {
            System.out.println("You typed quit");
            System.out.println("check: " + console.hasNext()); // This line doesnt print
            bool = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If your `Scanner` is declared as `System.in`, it will be asking `System.in` if there is a next value to be received. The `in` class will then wait for the user to input something, then return true.

Reserve `hasNext()` for things like files, where the input size is fixed. That way, when `Scanner` queries the file, it has a definite `hasNext()`.

Instead, I suggest grabbing the next value as a String, then checking if it matches the integer format. If it does, then convert it, otherwise, handle it however you'd like.