# How to break while loop when see empty line in Java?

Tags: java, while-loop

> Write a code that reads a list of student grades from standard input line-by-line until there are no more lines to read or an empty line is encountered.

However, I cannot exit the loop anyway. I tried to write
`Scanner input = new Scanner(input.hasNext());` and else break but it is not working

```
public class NumInput {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    float min = Float.MAX_VALUE;
    float max = Float.MIN_VALUE;
    float total=0;
    int count=0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (input.hasNext()) {

      float val = input.nextFloat();


      if (val < min) {
          min = val;
      }
      if (val > max) {
         max = val;
      }
      count++; 
      total += val ;
    }
    float average = (float) total / count;
    System.out.println("min: " + min);
    System.out.println("max: " + max);
    System.out.println("The Average value is: " + average);
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly happens when you execute that?

Comment: Works [here](http://ideone.com/eNuYJd)

Comment: Maybe this link can help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206813/how-to-terminate-scanner-when-input-is-complete

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exiting while loop in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305951/exiting-while-loop-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `while(input.hasNext());`, try `while(input.hasNextFloat());` if it's always going to be a `float` type.

Also, `while(input.hasNextFloat());` will continue reading the user's input until a non `float` value (or non `int` value) is entered. So you can enter `1` and `2` and finally `q`, then because `q` is not an `float`/`int` it'll exit the loop.

A more specific way of solving this would be to do the following:

```
while(input.hasNextLine()) {
    String command = input.nextLine();
    if(command.equals("")) {
        System.out.println("breaking out of the loop");
        break;
    }
    // rest of the code but make sure to use Float.parseFloat() on the `command`;
}
```

This documentation has good examples as well as explanation for `hasNextFloat()`, `hasNextLine()`, and `parseFloat()`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: What should I write command= Float.parseFloat(); in paranthesis

Comment: You want to put `command` into the `parseFloat()` parameter and it will parse `command` (a `String` type) into a `float` and return that value. So you would type something like `float f = Float.parseFloat(command);`

Comment: When I do this, `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Unknown Source)
 at NumInput.main(NumInput.java:18)` I get result after 3 inputs

Comment: `while (input.hasNextLine()) {
     String command = input.nextLine();
     if(command.equals(" ")) {
            System.out.println("breaking out of the loop");
            break;
        }

      float val = input.nextFloat();
      float f = Float.parseFloat(command);
`

Comment: Whenever you update your code, try to update on your actual post so that others can see.

But just remove the last two lines and replace it with `float val = Float.parseFloat(command);`.

Not only that but your `if(command.equals(" "))` is only checking to see if there is a space character entered. If that's the desired check, then you can leave it but it doesn't really match with the description on your post so just pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

To check empty line you can use `nextLine` instead of `nextFloat` then compare with `""`, here is working code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumInput {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    float min = Float.MAX_VALUE;
    float max = Float.MIN_VALUE;
    float total=0;
    int count=0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str;
    while (input.hasNextLine()) { 

       str = input.nextLine();
       if(str.equals(""))   //Check if it is empty line then break
           break;
      float val = Float.parseFloat(str);  //Convert string to float


      if (val < min) {
          min = val;
      }
      if (val > max) {
         max = val;
      }
      count++; 
      total += val ;
    }
    float average = (float) total / count;
    System.out.println("min: " + min);
    System.out.println("max: " + max);
    System.out.println("The Average value is: " + average);
  }
}
```