# Can one make hasNext() case insensitive?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

My main menu is inside the while loop that checks if user wants to quit.

```
while(!sc.hasNext("quit")){
   ...}
```

Can I make hasNext() case insensitive, so user can type any variation of cases in word 'quit', like QuIt or quIt ?

Comment: Yes. [Read the Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). The `Scanner.hasNext(String)` is a pattern. You can also use the `Scanner.hasNext(Pattern)` if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the String pattern "^(?i)quit$" passed to the `sc.hasNext(String)` will work.

```
final String QUIT_PAT = "^(?i)quit$";
...
while (! sc.hasNext(QUIT_PAT)) {
  ...
}
```

I don't have an easy Scanner set up to test, but the regex should work.

However, I would suggest [read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847036/java-scanner-hasnext-doesnt-return-false?rq=1) that suggests embedding the check when using stdin might not be the best approach.

---

*Example Test Results of the regex:*
[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way around this is by taking the user input and automatically sending all chars in the sting to upper or lower case and then checking that. Then it wouldn't matter what the user put in.

```
String str1 = new String(); 
str1 = scanner.nextLine();
str1.toUpperCase();
while(str1.equals("QUIT")){....}
```

Comment: Um, no. You cannot do `str1 == "QUIT"`. String comparisons are not done that way in Java.

Comment: I know you need to use the .equals(), my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try like this:

```
String input = sc.next();
while(!input.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"){
 ...
}
```