# stop the program when user press enter key

Tags: java

Please test my code please.
I am trying to terminate my program when user press enter key or not texting anything.But my program is not terminate.Help me please!

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String a =s.nextLine();
        
        while(s.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(s.nextLine());
        }
```

Comment: Your program terminates when the EOF character is typed.

Comment: You can end this by typing a control-d or a control-z.

Answer (score 1):

You want it to echo whatever the user types until they hit enter without typing anything in?

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String a = s.nextLine();
while(!a.equals("")) {
    System.out.println(a);
    a = s.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: Your code has a bug in the while statement. It must be `!a.equals("")`, then it will work.

Comment: Thanks!  Hazards of coding in my phone browser.

Answer (score 0):

This thread might help you.
[Java Scanner hasNext() doesn't return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847036/java-scanner-hasnext-doesnt-return-false)

your s.hasNext() is pending in your code because the Scanner is on System.in